# TypeScript adding type support for a specific key in interface and matching value of the same

Tags: typescript

Take below example.

```
interface MyObj = {
   name: string;
   id: number;
   isMandatory?: boolean;
}
```

I have a function as below which takes one of key and value from 'MyObj'.

```
function sampleFn(key, value) {
   // do something
}
```

How can I add type checking in sampleFn function. eg.if I pass key as "id", it should first check that id is allowed and then value should be of "number" type.

Comment: could you give some examples?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean , you want to check the type of the value according key param ?

Comment: @nzrytmn Yes, first check whether attribute is one of the keys in object and then the type of value should match the corresponding key's value type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
interface MyObj {
   name: string;
   id: number;
   isMandatory?: boolean;
}

function sampleFn<K extends keyof MyObj>(key: K, value: MyObj[K]) {}

sampleFn('name', 'X'); // OK
sampleFn('number', 0); // Error, key does not exist
sampleFn('name', 0);   // Error, value is of incorrect type
```

In the example above, the `key` parameter is defined as having to be a key of the `MyObj` interface, and the `value` parameter as having to be of the type that corresponds to the property defined by `key`.